# Guice: add dependency in a method

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cucumber, guice

I have a Cucumber project using Selenium for end-to-end testing. My Page classes extend my BasePage and have @ScenarioScoped annotation for sharing state between the steps. I have a NavigationStepDefs class where I open different pages and my goal is to keep the page object so I can call it's methods in later steps by invoking them by name. The problem is that I have around 40 pages and I don't want to inject all of them in the NavigationStepDefs constructor. Is there a way to only inject one page when I need it in a method?

I tried adding an Injector for the page I need

```
    public void the_user_opens_the_Administration_page() {
        final Injector injector = Guice.createInjector();
        final SchedulesPage page = injector.getInstance(SchedulesPage.class);
        System.out.println(page.getProcess().getTagName());
```

But I get an error

````
1) No scope is bound to cucumber.runtime.java.guice.ScenarioScoped.```
````

Answer (score 0):

you don't have any modules installed with the bindings. 
so guice doesn't really know how the bindings inside the class are supposed to be made.